# Java API to implement query for script_fields in Elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have tried to find the answer of this question but couldn't find. The scenario is: I have to get one extra field which is the calculation of two fileds in the elastic search query result. For this purpose I am using script_fields.

```
"script_fields": {
      "result": {
        "script": "doc['feild1'].value / doc['field2'].value"
      }
    }
```

The query is working fine, and I am getting the correct result.
But now I have to implement the query in Java, I couldn't find any way to implement script_fields in Java.

Can somebody please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply using the `addScriptField()` method like this:

```
SearchResponse response = client().prepareSearch()
    .setQuery(matchAllQuery())
    .addScriptField("result", new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "groovy", "doc['field1'].value / doc['field2'].value", Collections.emptyMap()))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am using SearchResult API,

Comment: What do you mean by "SearchResult API"? Please update your question with the current code you have